# How to create property with set accessor acessible only outside of owner class

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I need a property where set is accessible only from constructor or outside of owner class (it can't be changed within class methods). Something opposite to a private modifier. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're the one that designs the class, can't you just.. not use it inside the class?

Comment: Doesn't sound possible.  It also sounds like an indication that something else is strangely wrong with the overall design.  Why do you want to do this?  I suppose *maybe* you could use a setter which uses reflection to check the type of the caller?  Of course, then the object could just directly set the backing field, so no gain there.

Comment: I need it, because this property is for business level logic, and I don't want to change it by accident inside internal methods and break upper logic.

Comment: Then don't change it by accident.  You can just select the variable find all references.

Comment: Accessibility in .NET is based on *trust*.  There is no scenario where you can trust code that you don't know about *more* than your own code.  It just plain doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Blam, of course I'll not change it by accident while it is in my mind. But after some time I can forget about it. Or if anyone another will modify the code.
OK, anyway, thanks for answers, I catched that if I need it very much - only way is to write additional wrapper around the class with this field.

Comment: If you going to code then everything about data and logic should be in your mind.  If you are in a position that you think you need to protect you from yourself then you are in a bad position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of weird. Because you are the one creating the class...make it public and just don't touch the property from inside the class (this can hold if you make sure to write unit tests to test the invariant when calling methods on the current class). But...if you really want something like this, I guess you need to wrap the properties in some other class which can only be accessed through a setter method on the current class. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable that your class needs to depends to, but can't change, it seems like it belongs in some other class or struct, which your class will only have a reference of.